# Object reference not set to an instance of an object - Http Client - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, api, http

i am testing an external API

first i am getting the token and all data from the API as showing below:

Controller:

```
public function index()
{
    $response = Http::post('http://example.com/authenticate', [
        'Username' => 'ADMIN',
        'Password' => 'ADMIN',
        'Token' => 'FK98DL-...',
    ]);
    $token = json_decode($response, true);


    $apiURL = 'http://example.com/api/Order/';
    $headers = [
        'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
        'Authorization' => $token,
    ];
    $response2 = Http::withHeaders($headers)->get($apiURL);
    $data = $response2->json();

    return view('api.auth.orders.index',compact ('data'));
}
```

and i am able to get the token and data from the above function

now in the next function to show a particular order:

```
public function show($DocNo)
{
 $response = Http::post('http://example.com/authenticate', [
    'Username' => 'ADMIN',
    'Password' => 'ADMIN',
    'Token' => 'FK98DL-...',
]);
$token = json_decode($response, true);

$response3 = Http::withHeaders(['Authorization' => $token,'Content-Type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'])->get('http://example.com/api/Order/GetOrder/', [
        'DocNo' => $DocNo,
    ])->json();
 return $response3;
```

from the above function i am getting this error:

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

i tested the "Show" function with Postman and i am able to get the response

[Postman Test Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FUuup.png)

api.php:

```
Route::get('show/{id}', 'show')->name('show');
```

anchor tag that will redirect to particular order in the view:

```
<a href="{{ route('orders.show', $item['DocNo'])}}">EDIT</a></td>
```

what seems to be the problem here?

Comment: `$response3 = Http::withHeaders(['Authorization' => $token,'Content-Type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'])->get('http://example.com/api/Order/GetOrder/'.$DocNo)->json();`

Comment: still the same, now i'm getting blank page

Comment: What `var_dump($DocNo)` returns

Comment: string(9) "SO-000038"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SOLUTION:

I used Guzzle and Psr7:

```
$client = new Client();
    $headers = [
        'Authorization' => $token,
        'Content-Type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    ];
    $options = [
        'form_params' => [
            'DocNo' => $DocNo
        ]
    ];
    $request = new Psr7Request('GET', 'http://example.com/api/Order/GetOrder/', $headers);
    $res = $client->sendAsync($request, $options)->wait();
    $data = $res->getBody();
    echo $data;
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use `asForm` method of Http client like:

```
$response3 = Http::asForm()->withHeaders(['Authorization' => $token])
->get('http://example.com/api/Order/GetOrder/', [
        'DocNo' => $DocNo,
    ]);
```

[Read more](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/http-client#sending-form-url-encoded-requests)

Comment: same problem `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`

Comment: can you try to use `->json()` method after getting response like `$response3->json`, but not after `get()`?

Comment: same problem but without double quotes

Comment: What `var_dump($response3)` returns? Do not parse it to json anywhere